# Is there a clean workaround for func.bind or _.partial losing the "use server"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

This does not work; I get `Event handlers cannot be passed to Client Component props.`

```
// outer.tsx
import _ from 'lodash';

export default function Outer() {
    async function clickHandler(index1: number, index2: number) {
        'use server';
        console.log(`CLICK at ${index1}, ${index2}`);
    }

    // index1/2 are indices from 2 nested for loops, so this is a simplification
    return <Inner onClick={_.partial(clickHandler, index1, index2)} />;
}

// inner.tsx
'use client';

interface InnerProps {
    onClick(): Promise<void>;
}

export default function Inner({ onClick }: InnerProps) {
    return <button className="cell" onClick={onClick} />;
}
```

But this works fine (with the caveats in comments):

```
// outer.tsx
export default function Outer() {
    // note this version has no arguments
    async function clickHandler() {
        'use server';
        console.log('CLICK received');
    }

    return <Inner onClick={clickHandler} />;
}

// inner.tsx
'use client';

interface InnerProps {
    onClick(): Promise<void>;
}

export default function Inner({ onClick }: InnerProps) {
    // note that without wrapping `onClick`, I get an error when this is clicked
    // error says "Only plain objects can be passed to Client Components from Server Components"
    return <button className="cell" onClick={() => onClick()} />;
}
```

I attempted to make a wrapper method (based on a guess after skimming https://jser.dev/react/2023/04/20/how-do-react-server-components-work-internally-in-react/ , particularly section 3.9). This *partially* seems to work, but also seems incomplete. Firstly, I'm having trouble getting the types right (stuff like `Parameters<_.Partial>` didn't work, either). Secondly, when I click the button, I get `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'workers')`. But, I don't get the original error, so this might be on the right track?

```
function partialServerFunction<
    A extends unknown[],
    R,
    F extends (...fnArgs: A) => Promise<R>
>(fn: F, ...partialArgs: A) {
    // Without this @ts-expect-error, I get 'A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter' on the `...partialArgs`
    // @ts-expect-error Partial has extremely complex type args. 
    const newFn = _.partial(fn, ...partialArgs);
    // @ts-expect-error React has this property
    newFn.$$typeof = Symbol.for('react.server.reference');

    return newFn;
}

/*
    in outer.tsx, this results in a type error:
    Type 'Function1<number, Promise<void>>' is not assignable to type '() => Promise<void>'.
        Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 1 or more, but got 0.ts(2322)
*/
<Inner onClick={partialServerFunction(clickHandler, arg1, arg2)} />
```